# How long does it usually take to erase cache?

Tags: nexus-5, fastboot, cache, factory-image

While in bootloader, I connected a USB cacble and ran this command to erase cache:

```
#> fastboot flash cache cache.img 
target reported max download size of 1073741824 bytes
erasing 'cache'...
```

**PROBLEM**: It has been running for 10 minutes already. The phone's screen still says `erasing...`.
The `cache.img` is 14 MB, downloaded from [Google](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images).

Should I give up?
About how long does it usually take? A few seconds, a few minutes, a few hours?

Comment: For a particular reason I can't use `erase`. Thanks for the info, feel free to make that an answer, thanks!

Comment: Just being curious: why would one want to download and flash a cache partition image?

Comment: @Izzy: I was wondering that too as well haha... `erase` does not work so I am trying to understand what is wrong. My phone is probably dead, so I might as well try that, never know, a miracle could occur :-)

Comment: If you have a "twin" of that device (or another device with a cache partition of the same size, or can create an image with an empty partition using the same file system), there might be another approach: finding what partition corresponds to it (i.e. `/dev/mmcblk*`), and then simply `cat cache.img > /dev/mmcblkX`. That's the approach I often use to flash recovery on devices not having a proper bootloader mode (like my LG P880), and also my [Adebar](https://github.com/IzzySoft/Adebar) creates scripts for ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>Why `flash cache`? Just `erase` or `format` would be enough.</strike>

Comment made me curious - care to share for what reason `erase` is unusable?

Either way it should only take a few seconds. Try flashing some other partitions (ones that won't touch your data, of course) and see if they pass.

Comment: `erase` actually fails on my device: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/154827/stuck-at-google-screen-recovery-mode-just-turns-the-screen-black I will need to try `format`.

Comment: Thanks for the score! I had an answer in that question too, didn't realize the 2 questions are linked together...

Comment: Also, I came across [link](https://www.reddit.com/r/nexus6/comments/38rxfn/fastboot_formatted_the_cache_getting_stuck_on/) which seems to indicate `format` is not a good idea. Anyway, you now have `format` and factory image as last resorts; if those fail I'd put the blame on hardware.